# Sharepoint JSOM Datetime convert automaticly

Tags: sharepoint

I am using the JSOM to get data from server.
There is a issue that when I get a value through by 'oListItem.get_item()' method.
Since the datatype of the value is sharepoint datetime,I always get a value varies according to the time zone.
I don't want this.
How can I get the origin date string?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint stores date in ISO-8601 format.
Just use `.toJSON()` method on a Date object and you will get the original date string in ISO-8601 format without your Timezone offset.